# This groundcheck system was included in the unity starter assets third person controller, but now it wont work. Why?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've found nothing about this. Here's the groundcheck `Grounded = Physics.CheckSphere(spherePosition, GroundedRadius, GroundLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);` how do I fix it?

Comment: Impossible to answer without the details. Please add the full script and more details

Comment: Is the ground marked ground?

Comment: the ground marked default, but the code looks for the default layer. also how do I post scripts longer than the character limit?

Answer (score 1):

Answer by hanisherif1997_unity in Unity forum : https://answers.unity.com/questions/1579825/physicschecksphere-not-working.html
Basically change the layer mask of player to a new layer like "Character" otherwise if it is Default, its player's collider is colliding in checkSphere

Comment: Weird things happened, the groundcheck system only works if I look up (it's a third person game), also, the video the guy mentions is unavailable. and my player was marked player while the ground was marked ground